# Grid Bag Layout doesnt recognize my commands?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Im making an application that uses a lot of constructors, and I understood that you cant use the Drag and Drop tool of netbeans for making a constructor, and i thought it was good idea to learn how to code fully organized windows, anyways I read a DEITEL Java book that uses a method for adding objects to the container, here it is:

```
private void addobject(Component componente, int column, int row, int width
int height){

//C will be the GridBagConstraints
//And I made a new GridBagLayout called "v"
//My Panel or container is called objcontainer and the LayoutManager is v 

c.gridx = column;
c.gridy = row; 

c.gridwidth = width;
c.gridheight = height;

v.setConstraints(componente, c);    
objcontainer.add(componente);

}
```

The method is declared in the same class in where the constructor is, it worked separating only by one gridy. But when I put it 2 or more away that the last object it just stays like if I put 1.

I dont know if thats how it works, also the anchors dont work perfectly, besides the LINE START one, the Center ones are failing.

Here is the code, anyways thanks:

```
package Windows;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class agregaringreso extends JDialog{

    private int ingreso;
    private String nombreingreso;   
    private String Frecuencia [] = {"Solo una vez", "Cada semana","Cada 2 semanas", "Cada 3 semanas", "Cada mes,"};

    Container contenedor;
    JPanel objcontainer;
    GridBagLayout esquema;
    GridBagConstraints c;

    JButton aceptar;
    JLabel title;
    JLabel ingreso2;
    JLabel nombreingreso2;
    JLabel frecuencia2;

    JTextField ingreso3;
    JTextField nombreingreso3;
    JComboBox frecuencia3;

    private void addobjeto(Component componente, int columna, int fila, int ancho, int alto){

        c.gridx = columna;  
        c.gridy = fila;

        c.gridwidth = ancho;
        c.gridheight = alto;

        esquema.setConstraints(componente, c);
        objcontainer.add(componente);


        }

  public agregaringreso(){

      setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      setTitle("Agregar Nuevo Ingreso - EkPek");
      pack();
      setResizable(false);
      setSize(500, 200);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);

      //FASE DE INICIALIZACION

      contenedor = getContentPane();
      objcontainer = new JPanel();
      esquema = new GridBagLayout();
      c = new GridBagConstraints();

      aceptar = new JButton("Aceptar");
      title = new JLabel("Agregar Nuevo Ingreso");
      ingreso2 = new JLabel("Monto del Ingreso: ");
      nombreingreso2 = new JLabel("Nombre del Ingreso: ");
      frecuencia2 = new JLabel("Frecuencia con la cual recibe el ingreso: ");
      ingreso3 = new JTextField("Escriba aqui el monto");


      nombreingreso3 = new JTextField("Escriba aqui el nombre");

      frecuencia3 = new JComboBox(Frecuencia);

      //FASE DE ACOMODO

      c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      addobjeto(title, 0, 0, 1, 1);

      c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
      addobjeto(nombreingreso2 , 0, 4, 1, 1);
      addobjeto(nombreingreso3, 1, 4, 1, 1);

      addobjeto(ingreso2, 0, 5, 1, 1);
      addobjeto(ingreso3, 1, 5, 1, 1 );

      addobjeto(frecuencia2, 0 , 6, 1, 1);
      addobjeto(frecuencia3, 1, 6, 1, 1);

      c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      addobjeto(aceptar,0 ,7 ,1, 1);


      contenedor.add(objcontainer);
      objcontainer.setLayout(esquema);




      setVisible(true);

}


}
```

Comment: Try using `objcontainer.add(componente, c);` instead.  Using `setConstraints` may not be working as the component is not yet been managed by the `GridBagLayout` (hasn't been added yet)

Comment: Didnt work, it just displays everything in the same row, but thanks for reading this big post.

Comment: I can see what the result of running the code is, but I don't know what you were expecting. Try to post some picture of what you want to get.

Comment: Also, class names should start with an uppercase.

Comment: @user1803551 Please don't leave sarcastic comments - fix the problem. You have the ability to edit posts, use it and take 30 seconds to make the site better, rather than adding needless sarcasm and hostility.

Comment: Yes @user1803551 I know I should use " ' " and follow the Java rules, but god, you are only putting bad grades on my noob questions that anyone has, and because that I cant post pictures.

Comment: You can post a link to the picture. Someone will edit it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it worked separating only by one gridy. But when I put it 2 or more away that the last object it just stays like if I put 1.

If you mean that jumping the value of `gridy` doesn't do anything than you're right, it's intended. The grid only consists of rows and columns which have components in them.

Example: if you have 2 components, the first at `(0,0)` and the second at `(0,4)`, then the `gridy` values 1 through 3 are not counted. The result is that the second component is actually at `(0,1)`. Same goes for `gridx`.

> also the anchors dont work perfectly, besides the LINE START one, the Center ones are failing.

In your example the `CENTER` `anchor` value is functioning as intended. If the component is smaller than its available space (and it was not instructed to fill that space with `fill`), it will be aligned to the center of the space.

What you probably want it for the component to be in the center of the whole grid, and not in the center of its available space. To do this, you must set it so that the component spans the grid's width (or height) by setting its `gridwidth` appropriately.

#### Picture comparison

[image] [image]

[@MadProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30314853/1803551) already explained how to fix your setup (I will mention it below in the notes). You're supposed to get the top picture after those corrections. The red lines separate rows and the blue lines separate columns - this is your grid.

You see that the components in the first and last rows are **centered in column 0** because this is their available space. In the bottom picture, they are **centered in both columns** since I instructed them to span 2 columns.

I also noted a space discrepancy in the top picture with a yellow rectangle. This happens because the components are not filling all their available space. While it's your choice, it is customary in such layout to do as shown in the bottom picture.

#### Code comparison

```
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER; // Redundant - default
addobjeto(title, 0, 0, 2, 1);

c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
addobjeto(nombreingreso2, 0, 1, 1, 1);
addobjeto(nombreingreso3, 1, 1, 1, 1);

addobjeto(ingreso2, 0, 2, 1, 1);
addobjeto(ingreso3, 1, 2, 1, 1);

addobjeto(frecuencia2, 0, 3, 1, 1);
addobjeto(frecuencia3, 1, 3, 1, 1);

c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
addobjeto(aceptar, 0, 4, 2, 1);
```

- Set the `gridwidth` of `title` and `aceptar` to 2 (`GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER` will also work) to allow them to span 2 columns.
- For the rest of the components, set `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;` to allow them to align nicely with themselves (yellow rectangle). Remember to reset it `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;` for `aceptar` if you don't want the button to strech.
- Specifying `c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;` is redundant for the first component as it is the default, but it can make the code clearer.

#### Notes:

- You don't need your `JLabel`s to be fields as you probably don't need to hold a reference to them. Local variables will do just as well and will decrease the memory usage.
- Class names should start with an uppercase (`Agregaringreso`).
- As for my "setup" (as MadProgrammer explained): before adding the components I have

  ```
  esquema = new GridBagLayout();
  objcontainer = new JPanel(esquema);
  c = new GridBagConstraints();
  ```

  and at the end I have

  ```
  getContentPane().add(objcontainer);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  setTitle("Agregar Nuevo Ingreso - EkPek");
  pack();
  setResizable(false);
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  setVisible(true);
  ```

  (You don't need to hold a reference to the content pane.)

Answer (score 2):

The order in which you do things is very important.  It pointless doing something like...

```
objcontainer = new JPanel();
esquema = new GridBagLayout();
// Add a bunch of stuff
objcontainer.setLayout(esquema);
```

You've basically added components to a container (which is using a `FlowLayout`) and then changed the layout manager.  The constraints won't carry across, they are typically incompatiable between layouts (what's a `FlowLayout` going to do with `GridBagConstraints` anyway)

Instead, set the layout first

```
objcontainer = new JPanel();
esquema = new GridBagLayout();
objcontainer.setLayout(esquema);
// Add components.
```

This also holds true for when you establish a window...

```
public agregaringreso(){

    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Agregar Nuevo Ingreso - EkPek");
    pack();
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(500, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

It's all kind of pointless, as you've not actually added anything to the window, so `pack` can't actually do it's job (it's got nothing to pack)

Instead, build the UI first, the "set up" the window properties...

```
public agregaringreso(){

    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Agregar Nuevo Ingreso - EkPek");

    //FASE DE INICIALIZACION
    contenedor = getContentPane();
    contenedor.setBackground(Color.RED);
    objcontainer = new JPanel();
    esquema = new GridBagLayout();
    objcontainer.setLayout(esquema);
    c = new GridBagConstraints();

    // Add components

    setResizable(false);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I love you, I still have the same problem but thanks for explaining the "functioning" because I asked a question about centering Windows and they told me It was like that. Thanks.. If I could post a pic I would do it...